# How to create a bootstrap-table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, bootstrap-table

I'm having trouble developing a bootstrap-table by clicking a button. My goal is to add a sort feature for each columns on a table. So for my user case, when a user clicks on the button, it calls an ajax to grab a data from Database and sends back a result (it works so no worries on it). So i need to display the results as a bootstrap-table so i can use the sort feature for each column. Plus, I'm using pagination.js which uses Array of json objects and table to display the result. 
When I develop the table and append it into a div, I dont see the sort feature on each columns.

It works when I create a simple hard code HTML table with Bootstrap-table attributes such as sort feature (data-sortable="true"). I believe when the page loads bootstrap detects the  and its attributs that is on the html body. But when I dynamically create a bootstrap-table, the HTML table is there but not the bootstrap-table feature.

Please help. Here is my code below of how i develop the table using javascript function.

```
// result is a large string of result when ajax is sending a response. 
function displayResult(result) {
    //convert the result into Array of JSON
    var splitResult = result.split("*split*");
    var getLast = splitResult.length - 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < splitResult.length; i++){
        if(i != getLast) {
            splitResult[i] = JSON.parse(splitResult[i]);
        } else {
            splitResult.splice(i,1);
        }
    }

       // the .pagination is a function that is use in pagination.js 
       // the #page is a DIV
    $('#page').pagination({
        dataSource: splitResult,
        pageSize: 8,
        callback: function(data, pagination) {
            // template method
             var html = template(data);
                // grab the html String and append it into the #demo DIV
            $("#demo").append(html); 
        }
    })
}


function template(data) {
    // table tag with bootstrap-table attributes
    var html = '<table data-toggle="table"  style="width: 100%;">';

    // create the table headers
    html = html + '<thead><tr><th data-field="IDCODE" data-sortable="true">ID</th><th scope="col" data-sortable="true">ZIP 11</th><th scope="col" data-sortable="true">Date</th></tr></thead>'
        + '<tbody>';

    // input the results of the data
    if (data[0].IDCODE) {
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        html += '<trid="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2"><td>'
                + item.IDCODE+'</td>' 
                + '<td>' + item.ZIP11_ID + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + item.DEL01_TS + '</td></tr>';
      });
    } else {
      $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        html += '<tr><td>'+ item +'</td></tr>';
      });
    }

    html += '</tbody></table>';

    return html;
  }
```

when using this approach, it just display the html table. Not using bootstrap-table. I'm trying to add a feature where a user can click on the column header to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code could help you, what it does is
1. display a textBox, where I user can enter a db table name
2. The backend ( in my case Python) get information from db_name_table 
3. The data is displayed dinamically in the bootstrap-table

HTML

```
 <form method="GET" id="id1" action="{% url 'request_page' %}">
        <input type="text" value="db_name_table" name="mytextbox" id='mytextbox' size="1"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Click" name="mybtn">
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
        $('#id1').submit( function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                url:  $(this).attr('action'),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success:function( value ){
                $('#datatable').bootstrapTable({
                    striped: true,
                    pagination: true,
                    showColumns: true,
                    showToggle: true,
                    showExport: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    paginationVAlign: 'both',
                    pageSize: 25,
                    pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 'ALL'],
                    columns: {{ columns|safe }},  
                    data: {{ data|safe }}, 
                    });
                }
            })
        })
    });
```

Comment: Syntax errors and what is bootstrapTable()? This cannot work. Plus you don't have #datatable in the HTML either.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                        var i = 1;
                        $('#tab_logic').on('focusout', 'tbody tr:nth-last-child(2) td:nth-last-child(2) input', function() {
                            if ($(this).val() != '' && $('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth-last-child(2) td:nth-last-child(3) input').val() != "" && $('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth-last-child(2) .product').val() != '') {
                                b = i - 1;
                                $('#addr' + i).html($('#addr' + b).html()).find('td:first-child').html(i + 1);
                                $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
                                $(this).focus().select();
                                i++;
                            }
                        });

                        $('body').on('click', '#delete_row', function() {
                            if (i > 1) {
                                var id = i;
                                $('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth-last-child(2)').remove();
                                $('#tab_logic tbody tr:last').attr("id", "addr" + (id - 1));
                                i--;
                            }
                            calc();
                        });

                        $('#tab_logic tbody').on('keyup change', function() {
                            calc();
                        });
                        $('#tax').on('focusout', function() {
                            var total = parseInt($('#sub_total').val());
                            var tax_sum = eval(total / 100 * $('#tax').val());
                            $('#tax_amount').val(tax_sum.toFixed(2));
                            $('#total_amount').val((tax_sum+total).toFixed(2));                        
                        });


                    });

                    function calc() {
                        $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
                            var html = $(this).html();
                            if (html != '') {
                                var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
                                var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
                                $(this).find('.total').val(qty * price);

                                calc_total();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    function calc_total() {
                        total = 0;
                        $('.total').each(function() {
                            total += parseInt($(this).val());
                        });
                        $('#sub_total').val(total.toFixed(2));
                        tax_sum = total / 100 * $('#tax').val();
                        $('#tax_amount').val(tax_sum.toFixed(2));
                        $('#total_amount').val((tax_sum + total).toFixed(2));
                    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes